# CloudFront not respecting Behavior Paths -> Origins

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm using AWS CDK to construct a CloudFront Ingress for various other microservices. It seems super inconsistent in when it works, normally only the first request, then it completely fails.

I'm making sure to invalidate the entire distribution and making sure everything has updated before I test any changes, but I'm having no luck.

My goal is:

- `/graphql` -> API Gateway
- `/app/*` -> S3 Website Bucket (App Static SPA)
- `* (Default)` -> S3 Website Bucket (Website Static SPA)

I'm using a CloudFront Function to rewrite requests for the non-default origins to remove the prefix:

```js
/* eslint-disable */
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    request.uri = request.uri.replace(/^\/[^/]*\//, '/');
    return request;
}
```

Which, when testing via Console, works as expected (`/app/login` becomes `/login`, etc.)

However what seems to happen is the origins aren’t respected after maybe 1 request, sometimes 0, and it defaults to the * behavior.

My main `ingress` CDK Stack is defined using this:

```js
import { CloudFrontAllowedMethods, CloudFrontWebDistribution, SSLMethod, ViewerCertificate, SecurityPolicyProtocol, FunctionEventType, Function, FunctionCode, ViewerProtocolPolicy, Behavior, OriginProtocolPolicy, PriceClass } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudfront';
import { DnsValidatedCertificate } from '@aws-cdk/aws-certificatemanager';
import { ARecord, HostedZone, RecordTarget } from '@aws-cdk/aws-route53';
import { CloudFrontTarget } from '@aws-cdk/aws-route53-targets';
import { Metric } from '@aws-cdk/aws-cloudwatch';
import { Construct, Duration } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { Aws, Stack } from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { createGraphQL } from '../graphql';
import { createSite } from '../site';
import { createApp } from '../app';
import type { StackProps } from './types';

export async function createIngress(scope: Construct, id: string, props: StackProps) {
    const stack = new Stack(scope, `${id}-${props.environment}`, props);

    const serviceProps = {
        environment: props.environment,
        root: props.root,
        core: props.core,
    };

    // Create the various Services for the Ingress.
    const app = await createApp(stack, 'app-resources', serviceProps);
    const site = await createSite(stack, 'site-resources', serviceProps);
    const graphql = await createGraphQL(stack, 'graphql-resources', serviceProps);

    // Fetch the DNS Zone.
    const zone = HostedZone.fromLookup(stack, 'ingress-zone', {
        domainName: props.domainName,
    });

    // Ensure there is a Certificate and fetch the ARN.
    const { certificateArn } = new DnsValidatedCertificate(stack, 'ingress-cert', {
        domainName: props.domainName,
        hostedZone: zone,
        region: 'us-east-1', // Cloudfront only checks this region for certificates.
    });

    // Fetch the Viewer Certificate.
    const viewerCertificate = ViewerCertificate.fromAcmCertificate({
        certificateArn: certificateArn,
        env: {
            region: Aws.REGION,
            account: Aws.ACCOUNT_ID,
        },
        node: stack.node,
        stack,
        metricDaysToExpiry: () => new Metric({
            namespace: 'TLS Viewer Certificate Validity',
            metricName: 'TLS Viewer Certificate Expired',
        }),
    }, {
        sslMethod: SSLMethod.SNI,
        securityPolicy: SecurityPolicyProtocol.TLS_V1_2_2021,
        aliases: [props.domainName],
    });

    const rewriteFunction = new Function(stack, 'rewrite-function', {
        functionName: 'origin-rewrite',
        comment: 'Rewrites Microservice paths for origin',
        code: FunctionCode.fromFile({
            filePath: './functions/rewrite.js',
        }),
    });

    // Create the CloudFront Ingress.
    const distribution = new CloudFrontWebDistribution(stack, 'ingress-distribution', {
        comment: 'Ingress',
        viewerCertificate,
        viewerProtocolPolicy: ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
        priceClass: PriceClass.PRICE_CLASS_ALL,
        defaultRootObject: 'index.html',
        originConfigs: [{
            /**
             * GraphQL
             */
            customOriginSource: {
                domainName: graphql.url,
                originProtocolPolicy: OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTPS_ONLY,
            },
            behaviors: [{
                pathPattern: 'graphql',
                defaultTtl: Duration.seconds(0),
                minTtl: Duration.seconds(0),
                maxTtl: Duration.seconds(0),
                compress: true,
                allowedMethods: CloudFrontAllowedMethods.GET_HEAD,
                forwardedValues: {
                    queryString: true,
                    cookies: { forward: 'all' },
                },
                functionAssociations: [{
                    function: rewriteFunction,
                    eventType: FunctionEventType.VIEWER_REQUEST,
                }],
            }],
        }, {
            /**
             * App
             */
            customOriginSource: {
                domainName: app.staticSite.bucket.bucketWebsiteDomainName,
                originProtocolPolicy: OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTP_ONLY,
            },
            behaviors: [{
                pathPattern: 'app/*',
                compress: true,
                allowedMethods: CloudFrontAllowedMethods.GET_HEAD,
                forwardedValues: {
                    queryString: true,
                    cookies: { forward: 'all' },
                },
                functionAssociations: [{
                    function: rewriteFunction,
                    eventType: FunctionEventType.VIEWER_REQUEST,
                }],
            }],
        }, {
            /**
             * Website (Fallback)
             */
            customOriginSource: {
                domainName: site.staticSite.bucket.bucketWebsiteDomainName,
                originProtocolPolicy: OriginProtocolPolicy.HTTP_ONLY,
            },
            behaviors: [{
                isDefaultBehavior: true,
                compress: true,
                allowedMethods: CloudFrontAllowedMethods.GET_HEAD,
                forwardedValues: {
                    queryString: true,
                    cookies: { forward: 'all' },
                },
            }],
        }],
    });

    // Create a DNS Record for the CloudFront Ingress.
    new ARecord(stack, 'ingress-record', {
        recordName: props.domainName,
        target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new CloudFrontTarget(distribution)),
        zone,
    });

    return { stack, app, site, graphql };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the response headers from S3 & API Gateway needed to be changed to account for `Cache-Control` - using a Lambda@Edge to modify them to *not* be cached, as well as the `ttl` configuration, solved the issue.